Encryption error trying to connect the JPA Console in Intelij
I have a working spring boot application with an application-local.yml that contains a valid connection string.
The application works fine and the connection string has the necessary encrypt = false.
url: jdbc:sqlserver://LOCALHOST;databaseName=test;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=false

However, it seems that this connection string is not used by the JPA Console in Intelij.
The console cannot connect to the database due to encryption issues.
How do I change the console settings so that it doesn't use encryption?

The JPA Console settings clearly state in the facet settings that there are automatically detected descriptor settings in the application.yaml and application-local.yaml
